# Is it possible to generate email as soon as someone updates file within tortoisesvn and send the email to users who has access to that folder?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm looking into possible ways to incorporate email functionality with file commit in TortoiseSVN. I wanted to know whether its possible to generate and send email to users who have access to the relevant folder whenever a file is updated/added within that folder.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How much effort have you put into researching this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You should [use server-side repository hook scripts](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/create/#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) to send email notifications about repository changes. For commit email notifications you can use [a post-commit hook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/post-commit/) script. Here are your options:

1. Write the post-commit hook script from the scratch using any programming or scripting language you prefer. The simplest example: the post-commit can call [`svnlook changed` command-line](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnlook/c/changed/) to get the list of changed paths and then send emails if changed paths match some pattern you specify in your hook's code.
2. Take and configure one of the email notification scripts from the official Apache Subversion repository:

   - [mailer.py Python script](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/mailer/),
   - [commit-email.rb Ruby script](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/commit-email.rb?view=markup).
3. If you use VisualSVN Server, then [you can use `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe` hook script that supports sending emails based on the repository path changed in the revision](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/). For example,

> ```
>   "%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
>      commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
>      --filter "/MyProject/trunk" ^
>      --from commits@example.com --to distributiongroup@example.com ^
>      --smtp-server smtp.example.com
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a "Commit Monitor" tool related to TortoiseSVN which users can install to get taskbar notifications when someone commits to a watched location.